# Set TabPanelSelected on Change of another Select Field

Tags: jquery, addclass

I am amending this post because I didnt give enough info.
Here is the link to the page http://www.pinkequine.com/shop/mattes.php

I wanted to be able to - on changing - the select button Product which has a DIV ID of `productordered` to reset the tabbed panel with a Div ID of `TabbedPanels1`

to this particular panel as `TabbedPanelSelected` each time the product changes.

```
<li class="TabbedPanelsTab 0 TabbedPanelsTabSelected" tabindex="0">Sheepskin</li>
```

I tried this but its not working

```
$(".0").addClass("#TabbedPanelsTabSelected");
$(".1,.2,.3,.4,.5,.6").removeClass("#TabbedPanelsTabSelected");
```

Comment: Hey, not clear with your requirement, but at a glance of the below code, i think, you have to refer this: https://api.jquery.com/siblings/ will help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the # signs from your addClass and removeClass

```
$(".0").addClass("TabbedPanelsTabSelected");
$(".1,.2,.3,.4,.5,.6").removeClass("TabbedPanelsTabSelected");
```

The # signs are for when you are going after an element with its ID tag

```
<div id="MyDiv"></div>
```

addClass and removeClass are for going after an element with its class element

```
<div class="SomeClass"></div>
```

In your case you are not using IDs, and do not want to. Just remove the # signs.